# Alternative for Zend Job Queue

Tags: php, queue, jobs, zend-server

Is it alternative solution for Zend Job Queue what could be used without Zend Server ?

My application need to accept quick request and provide quick response (receipt) and limit this part to database entry. After this additional process should be executed in background to analyze this request (generate PDF file, send emails with PDF, send text message, etc) I do not want to initial request to wait for all those actions to finish - just provide receipt and let server do it a few seconds later...

Zend Job Queue would be a perfect solution, however I can not effort Zend Server environment at this moment. 
Cron job run every minute is not good way: ( up to 60 seconds delay, and checking database every minute for new entries instead on demand ).

How would you tackle this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously I used the BSD lpd for queue management (in my case to queue access for a modem handling SMS and fax, rather than for demand management). But there are lots of other tools available. e.g. [rabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html),  [Dropr](https://github.com/s0enke/dropr/),  [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/)

Comment: Do any of those services support scheduling, or are the only messaging? (i.e. run jobs at specific times, accurate to seconds)

Comment: They're message handling systems. IME, if you think you need to run batch processing at that level of accuracy then you're already doing lots of things wrong.

Comment: The OP asked about Zend Job Queue, which has scheduling functionality.  I asked the question to clarify to other readers as I suspected what you confirmed - that the tools offered in the answer don't have scheduling functions as they're mainly messaging solutions.  btw, nobody mentioned batch processing (and Zend Job Queue does have second-resolution scheduling - which can be a very long time in some applications).

Answer (score 0):

It's an old topic but I wes looking for a zend queue replacement too.
Laravel queues seems to be the most similar library: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues